# facebook share doesn't work, when click share from the action bar

Tags: android, xml, facebook, android-activity, android-actionbar

I've used the below code to place a share button in the action bar, well to share particular text. When I click share, it works with messaging and email etc but when I click facebook. Facebook is opened on the create status bit, although the share text  from my below code is not there.

What have I done wrong? Or is there something I need to add or change?

**XML:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:title="Share"
            android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
    </menu>
```

**ActivityMain:**

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar_share_menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
        ShareActionProvider myShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent();
        myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Whatever message you want to share");
        myIntent.setType("text/plain");
        myShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(myIntent);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook might be looking for the EXTRA_SUBJECT.

*Untested too many trolls on FB.*

```
private Intent createShareIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String s = getString(R.string.shareText);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, s);
    s = getString(R.string.sharesubject);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, s);
    return shareIntent;
}
```

using appcompat actionbar.

```
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

    // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat
            .getActionProvider(menuItem);

    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
```